# Get shipping address from order, woo commerce

Tags: woocommerce

Hello I cant get from woocommerce order shipping address, I get error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function get_formatted_address() on a non-object in ..**

I am using code:

```
$order_data = new WC_Order('12');

print_r($order_data->get_formatted_shipping_address());
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is  a workaround

```php
// 123 Happy Coding Lane, Apt #5 Delray Beach, FL 33445

function formatted_shipping_address($order)
{
    return
        $order->shipping_address_1 . ', ' . 
        $order->shipping_address_2 . ' ' .
        $order->shipping_city      . ', ' .
        $order->shipping_state     . ' ' .
        $order->shipping_postcode;
}

echo formatted_shipping_address($order);
```

You can access the shipping & billing properties directly.

*Shipping*

```
$order->shipping_first_name
$order->shipping_last_name
$order->shipping_company
$order->shipping_address_1
$order->shipping_address_2
$order->shipping_city
$order->shipping_state
$order->shipping_postcode
$order->shipping_country
```

*Billing*

```
$order->billing_first_name
$order->billing_last_name
$order->billing_company
$order->billing_address_1
$order->billing_address_2
$order->billing_city
$order->billing_state
$order->billing_postcode
$order->billing_country
```

Comment: the country name is saved with 2-3 digit code, to get the full country name use  
    WC()->countries->countries[ $order->billing_country ]  or  
    WC()->countries->countries[ $order->shipping_country ]

Answer (score 6):

You can get all the shipping address fields very simple, with this code that work for me:

**Code**:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id); // Order id
$shipping_address = $order->get_address('shipping'); 

print_r($shipping_address);
```

The function `get_address()` by default returns the billing address details but you can get the shipping address details passing the parameter '**shipping**'

Here are the docs: [Woocommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_address)

Regards!!

Answer (score 4):

Remove single quotes because WC_Order constructor accepts integer parameter order id.

```
 $order_data = new WC_Order(12);

 print_r($order_data->get_formatted_shipping_address());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    $order->get_shipping_address_1();    
    $order->get_shipping_address_2();
```